Asymptotic Distribution and Describe Sources of Increasing Power in an hypothesis testing problem
I am currently dealing with the following problem in a past exam (with no solution):

Suppose $S$ follows the Poisson distribution with mean $2\lambda>0$, here $\lambda$ is a parameter. Another two random variables $X,Y$ are conditionally independent Bernoulli random variables given $S=s$, and have the following distribution
$$P(X=1|S=s)=2^{-1-s},\,P(Y=1|S=s)=2^{-s}\theta.$$
Here $\theta\in(0,1)$ is a second parameter and $S$ is unobservable. Assume we observed $n$ i.i.d. copies $(X_i,Y_i)$ of $(X,Y)$.


(1) Find the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_n:=\frac{\bar{Y}_n}{2\bar{X}_n}$, where $\bar{X}_n,\bar{Y}_n$ are the means of $X_i,Y_i$.

I think we may use multivariate central limit theorem to solve this problem. It is clear that
$$E(X)=E(E(X|S))=E(2^{-S-1})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{s\geq0}e^{-2\lambda}\frac{(2\lambda)^s}{s!}2^{-s}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda}.$$
Similarly $E(Y)=E(E(Y|S))=\theta e^{-\lambda}.$ Note that
$$E(XY)=E(E(XY|S))=E(E(X|S)E(Y|S))=\frac{\theta}{2}E(2^{-2S})=\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-\frac{3}{2}\lambda}.$$
So $Cov(X,Y)=\frac{\theta}{2}(e^{-\frac{3}{2}\lambda}-e^{-2\lambda}).$ The variances are given by
$$Var(X)=E(E(X^2|S))-E(X)^2=E(E(X|S))-E(X)^2=E(X)-E(X)^2=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2\lambda}.$$
$$Var(Y)=E(E(Y^2|S))-E(Y)^2=E(E(Y|S))-E(Y)^2=E(Y)-E(Y)^2=\theta e^{-\lambda}-\theta^2 e^{-2\lambda}.$$
So by central limit theorem, we know that
$$\sqrt{n}((\bar{X}_n,\bar{Y}_n)-(EX,EY))\to N((0,0),\begin{bmatrix}Var(X)&Cov(X,Y)\\Cov(X,Y)&Var(Y)\end{bmatrix}).$$
From continuity mapping theorem we can derive an asymptotic distribution, but I don't know how to calculate it.

(2) Consider testing $H_0:\theta=0.5$ v.s. $H_1:\theta\neq0.5$. Construct an exact test statistic. Describe the sources of increasing power as $\theta$ moves away from $0.5$.

Now here are my questions:
(a) Am I doing the right thing in the first problem? If yes, then what is the asymptotic distribution?
(b) For (2) I don't know how to construct an exact test statistic(Maybe I can use $\hat{\theta}_n$ constructed in (a)? But the asymptotic distribution is unclear to me.), and I don't know how to summarize the sources of increasing power. Can you give me some hints or guidance?
Any help will be appreciated!

In this answer, I will give multiple hints and ways to deal with the problem.
For (1) I would use the delta method to deduce the asymptotic distribution of the $\widehat{\theta}_n$.
For (2) I would choose $c_{\alpha}$ such that $$\mathbb P\left(\left|\widehat{\theta}_n - \frac12\right| > c_{\alpha} \Big |\, \theta=\frac12\right) = \alpha$$
Now you can use the asymptotic distribution to find the value of $c_\alpha$. After that, you can compute the power of the test as:
$$1-\beta = \mathbb P\left(\left|\widehat{\theta}_n - \frac12\right| \le c_{\alpha} \Big |\,\theta\right)$$ as a function of $\theta$ and you will se that the function has $\frac12$ as it minimum.
